# How to execute Pipeline for Atlassian Plugin Project

Tags: java, maven, pipeline, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I'm trying to setup Pipeline for Atalassian JIRA Plugin project but it's failing with the following error:

```
The project com.xxx.jira.myplugin:jira-myplugin:0.0.1 (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/pom.xml) has 2 errors
[ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin com.atlassian.maven.plugins:jira-maven-plugin:8.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.atlassian.maven.plugins:jira-maven-plugin:jar:8.0.0: Could not transfer artifact com.atlassian.maven.plugins:jira-maven-plugin:pom:8.0.0 from/to atlassian-public (https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public): Connection reset -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     Unknown packaging: atlassian-plugin @ line 18, column 16
```

**Atlas SDK Version:**

```
ATLAS Version:    8.0.7
ATLAS Home:       C:\Applications\Atlassian\atlassian-plugin-sdk-8.0.7
ATLAS Scripts:    C:\Applications\Atlassian\atlassian-plugin-sdk-8.0.7\bin
ATLAS Maven Home: C:\Applications\Atlassian\atlassian-plugin-sdk-8.0.7\apache-maven-3.5.4
AMPS Version:     8.0.0
```

**Pipeline file:**

```
image: refinedwiki/atlassian-plugin-sdk:latest

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - atlas-version
          - atlas-mvn test
```

**pom.xml**

```xml
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>jira-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${amps.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <productVersion>${jira.version}</productVersion>
                    <productDataVersion>${jira.version}</productDataVersion>
                    <!-- Uncomment to install TestKit backdoor in JIRA. -->
                    <!--
                    <pluginArtifacts>
                        <pluginArtifact>
                            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira.tests</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jira-testkit-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>${testkit.version}</version>
                        </pluginArtifact>
                    </pluginArtifacts>
                    -->
                    <enableQuickReload>true</enableQuickReload>
                    <!-- See here for an explanation of default instructions: -->
                    <!-- https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/advanced-topics/configuration-of-instructions-in-atlassian-plugins -->
                    <instructions>
                        <Atlassian-Plugin-Key>${atlassian.plugin.key}</Atlassian-Plugin-Key>
                        <!-- Add package to export here -->
                        <Export-Package>com.xxx.jira.myplugin.api,</Export-Package>
                        <!-- Add package import here -->
                        <Import-Package>org.springframework.osgi.*;resolution:="optional", org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.*;resolution:="optional", *</Import-Package>
                        <!-- Ensure plugin is spring powered -->
                        <Spring-Context>*</Spring-Context>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${atlassian.spring.scanner.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>atlassian-spring-scanner</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <scannedDependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
                            <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-external-jar</artifactId>
                        </dependency>
                    </scannedDependencies>
                    <verbose>false</verbose>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Proxy/Firewall issue?

Comment: @JFMeier How can I confirm this? And if it is, what's fix?